# Spark DataFrame append row n-time based on a weight col value

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, rdd

What i'm trying to do is to "over sample" a small csv file with a weight value column present in each row.

```
Age|City|Weight
20 | NY |2
30 | SF |3
```

to

```
 Age|City|
 20 | NY |
 20 | NY |
 30 | SF |
 30 | SF |
 30 | SF |
```

With panda and np i did this

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv',low_memory=False)
weights=round(df.weight)
df.loc[np.repeat(df.index.values,weights)]
```

But it's too slow, it use 100% of 1 CPU (on 15 available) and all of 65G memory during more than 24h and finally crash.
The final file should contain more 70 millions rows.

So i try with Spark.

`rdd.map(lamba x: rdd.udf())` or something like this, combined with `explode()` should help but i don't understand how to make it right.
At the end, i need to save the DataFrame or RDD in one CSV not partitioned : a csv that i can use back with panda.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing that suggests you need Spark if you can load the data in memory and if you plan to read the output locally with Pandas. Just make it simple

```py
import csv

with open("input.csv") as fr, open("output.csv", "w") as fw:
    reader = csv.reader(fr)
    writer = csv.writer(fw)
    for age, city, weight in reader:
        if age == "age":
            writer.writerow((age, city))
        else:
            writer.writerows((age, city) for _ in range(int(weight)))
```

or with larger number of columns (I assume that weight is the last column, adjust according to the shape of real data):

```
with open("input.csv") as fr, open("output.csv", "w") as fw:
    reader = csv.reader(fr)
    writer = csv.writer(fw)
    for row:
        if row[0] == "age":
            writer.writerow(row[:-1])  
        else:
            writer.writerows(row[:-1] for _ in range(int(row[-1])))
```

Comment: I made the exemple very simple but the real file have 246 columns for 40k lignes, the weight is between 2000 and 5000 on each line.I try your suggestion right now with 3 cols, it will take  hours.  Hope it dont crash.

Comment: This doesn't really affect the answer. Just adjust the columns (you don't have to enumerate these).

Comment: Its running but use all memory and starting to Swap a lot and 100% of 1 CPU. I just need to run it once so cross fingers with me.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i manged to make it run thanks:

```
with open("file_in.csv",encoding='utf-8') as fr, open("file_out.csv", "w",encoding='utf-8') as fw:
reader = csv.reader(fr)
writer = csv.writer(fw)

for row in reader:
    if row[0] == "firstColName" :
        writer.writerow(row[:-1])  
    else:
        writer.writerows(row[:-1] for _ in range(int(row[-1])))
```